# IndexedDB - IDBKeyRange on simple index with arbitrary key list

Tags: html, indexeddb

I have an object store in an IDB that has a simple (non-compound) index on a field X. This index is not unique (many items may have the same value for X).

I'd like to query the IDB to return all items that have an X value of either "foo", "bar", or "bat".

According to the documentation, index `getAll` takes either a key (in my case a string) or an IDBKeyRange. However, it's not obvious to me how to construct an IDBKeyRange with an arbitrary set of keys, and get the union of all results based on those keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in a single request. indexedDB does not currently support "OR" style queries.

An alternative solution is to do one request per value. Basically, for each value, use getAll on the index for the value, then concatenate all of the arrays into a single array (possibly merging duplicates). You don't actually have that many round trips against the DB since you are using getAll. In setting up this index, you basically want a store of let's say "things", where each "thing" has a property such as "tags", where tags is an array of the values (each being a string). The index you create on the "tags" property should be flagged as a multi-entry index.

There are, of course, creative hacky solutions. Here is one. Keep in mind it is completely useless if you have things that have different tag sets but you still want to match the ones that share, this would only work if you do not care about whether any one thing has extra tags. For example, consider each distinct set of values, ignoring order. Let's call them groups. E.g. foo is 1, bar is 2, bat is 3, foo-bar is 4, foo-bat is 5, bar-bat is 6, etc.  You can give each group a key, like the numerical counter value I just used in the example. Then you can store the group key as a property in the object. Each time you go to store the object, calculate its group key. You can precalculate all group keys, or develop a hash-style function that generates a particular key given a set of arbitrary string values. Sure, you pay a tiny bit more upfront at time of storage, and when building the request query, but you save a ton of processing because indexedDB does all the processing after that. So you want a simple fast hash. And sure, this is added complexity. But maybe it will work. Just find a simple JS hash. Modify it so that you lexicographically store the value set prior to use (so that difference in value order does not cause difference in hash value). So, to explain more concretely, for the things object store, each thing object has a property called "tags-hash". You create a basic index on this (not unique, not multi-entry). Each time you put a thing in the store, you calculate the value of tags-hash, and set the property's value, before calling put. Then, each time you want to query, you calculate the hash of the array of tags by which you wish to query, then call `getAll(calculated-hash-value)`, and it will give you all things that have those exact tags.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. That's really surprising to know "OR" is not natively supported, although I suspect under the hood they'd be doing multiple round trips anyway. I was hoping to avoid the "compound key" field approach but that may be my only option from a performance perspective, although I'll try multiple round trips first.